# Create Anchor in files other than html

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

I want to create a markdown file where I specify certain points in code where specific function are (e.g. `Mainmenu.js:HomeScreen()`)

I know you can link a file in a markdown link (e.g. `[MainMenu](./MainMenu.js)` ).
The problem is that I havent found an option to create anchors in files other than html.
I want to write `[HomeScreen](./MainMenu.js#homescreen)` or something simular and this brings me to the function or anchor `homescreen` in the `MainMenu.js`.

Is this possible?

tanks for any advice

Comment: What Markdown tool are you using?

Comment: @chris I am using the Intellij build-in tool.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238096